# Can't get my jsfiddle to run knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, jsfiddle

I am trying to follow along with the documentation for the options bindings from this page:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

I can't seem to get the options to show up in the select. I am suspecting that it is in the references...but I have added knockout.

Here is the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bensjones/xhyBY/2/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke `​ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​`

http://jsfiddle.net/gZgU8/